# Connect to a different subnet

Tags: network

network map

**Modem** 4G (**192.168.0.1**) Subnet Mask: **255.255.255.240** <<<< **ROUTER** **10.0.4.1** / Subnet Mask: **255.255.255.0**, Gateway **192.168.0.1** (modem) (then Netgear orbi for wifi AP) <<< clients

can a client (either iOS or MacOs) use the modem DHCP and totally bypass the router (even though the first node is the router) ?

From my test the answer is no but I might did something wrong, I setup a the modem as geteway with an IP within the modem DHCP and the modem sub.

Perhaps I need to setup a static root?

alternatively can I connect to my router guest DHCP? same sub but different IP range (192.168.2.1)

Comment: I'm confused what you are trying to do. Are you trying to connect your Mac or iOS device directly to the modem instead of going through the router?

Comment: Yes, just want to get an IP from the modem DHCP directly and bypass the router network